# Divide array into two equal parts with minimal difference and Find sum of each part

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures, sum, integer

Hi I am trying to solve a problem with brute force, but I cannot wrap my head around how to solve it. I tried for hours.

Consider an array inputArray with atleast two non-zero positive integers ranging between 1 to 300 inclusive. Divide the arrayr into two groups based on these rules.

1. Each integer should belong to one of the two groups
2. The total sum of integers in each of the groups must be as nearly equal as possible.
3. The total number of integers between the 2 groups should not differ by more than 1

I need to return the sums of each group

Comment: This problem is np-complete. You will find some informations here : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem

Comment: @Basto although it is true that the problem is np-complete in general, the question is explicitly asking for a bruteforce solution, suggesting they will be limited to a relatively small input.

Comment: @alti21: you say "I tried for hours". What did you try? Which difficulties did you encounter? What does "with brute force" inspire you?

Comment: @Stef Yes but in the wiki article, in the "Exact algorithms" part, some bruteforce algorithm are describe. And btw, the 3rd rules will reduce the time of these algorithms

Comment: @Stef I am unable to see what pattern this problem has

Comment: Forget about patterns. What does "brute force" mean to you?

Comment: @Stef I'm just trying to solve the problem without any optimizations for now

Comment: Okay, great. So what does "brute force" suggest to you?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem using c++

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
vector<int> v;
int ans(int i,int n,float s)
{
  if(i<n-1) return INT_MAX;
  if(n==0) return abs(s);
  return min(ans(i-1,n-1,s-v[i-1]),ans(i-1,n,s));
}
 
int main()
{
  string s;
  cin>>s;
  int c=0;
  for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++)
  {
    if(s[i]==',') {v.push_back(stoi(s.substr(c,i-c)));
    c=i+1;}
  }
  v.push_back(stoi(s.substr(c,s.length()-c)));
   //for(int i=0;i<v.size();i++) cout<<v[i];
  int ss=0;
  for(int i=0;i<v.size();i++) ss+=v[i];
  int n1=v.size();
  int n2=n1/2;
  float su=ss/2;
  int k=ans(n1-1,n2,su);
  cout<<ss-su-k<<" "<<su+k;
 
}
```

this is solution for this
I hope this helped you

[output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZiu5.png)